# Unable to show layers in ArcGIS map after removing tiled map service layer

Tags: layer, arcgis-js-api

This is a Esri ArcGIS specific question.

I wish to create a function to change basemap.

To test the concept, I created a map and added a ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer

```
var tiled = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer('http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/NatGeo_World_Map/MapServer');
```

Next, I will remove the layer and add a ArcGISImageServiceLayer to stimulate a change basemap action

```
var image = new ArcGISImageServiceLayer("http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Toronto/ImageServer", {
  imageServiceParameters: params,
  opacity: 0.75
});
```

What I realised is after these [*adding tiled, removing tiled, adding image*] actions, no layers will be rendered

I tested other scenarios and these are the results:

```
1) If I do not remove the tiled layer, both layers get rendered
2) If I add only image layer, image layer get rendered
3) If I add only tiled layer, tiled layer get rendered
```

Do you guys have any advice as to why I cannot perform a remove layer action?

To make this question understandable, I created a sample fiddle that can illustrate my case. Simply remove the removeLayer comment in the fiddle and run it. You will notice as mentioned, nothing will be rendered.

https://jsfiddle.net/82qjh0wg/

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the basemap layer (which will be the first layer you add to the map if you don't specify the basemap layer in the constructor) then the entire map object will stop rendering.

If you want to hide the basemap layer then your best option is to either use css or [create a blank basemap](https://gisnuts.com/terra/blog/2014/01/28/how-to-create-a-blank-basemap-for-arcgis-online) and change the basemap to that.

You could also set the transparency of the basemap to hide it.

Comment: Hey Ryan, thanks for your comment, apologies that I did not update my question but I had resolved it by supplying the map with a set of zoom levels. Turns out the image layer is not displaying due to the zoom level set by the tiled layer not compatible with the image layer.